# Rotating font family with js

Tags: javascript, css, class, timer, setinterval

I'm very new to JS, I have a problem that could easily be solved I think but I can't figure it out :

I would like to find a way to change the font-family of an html element every 0.1 seconds without having to trigger something.

Basically I would like the html element to change font every 0.1 sec, rotating amongst 6 font families.

really thankful if you guys can find a way.

Louis

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. This question is off topic on SO

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
function changefontFamily() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("elementID");
  var font= ["Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica ", "Tahoma"];
  doc.style.fontFamily= font[i];
  i = (i + 1) % font.length;
}
setInterval(changefontFamily, 100);
<div id="elementID">text</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer !! you understood exactly what I would like to do, it doesn't seem to work though. Is it a syntax problem ? maybe quotes somewhere since JS needs it for changing CSS sometimes ? Is there any info I can get you that could help from here ?

Answer (score 0):

I set 1 second (1000 ms), for clarity, because 100ms is too fast

```js
(async()=>{
    const elem = document.getElementById('elementID');
    const fonts = ['Arial', 'Tahoma', 'Verdana'];

    let k = fonts.length;
    setInterval(()=>{
        k--;
        elem.style.fontFamily = fonts[k];
        console.log('Now:', fonts[k], k);
        if(k === 0)k = fonts.length;
    }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div id="elementID">Some Text to test it OUT</div>
```